# Should external links to blogspot and other blogging websites be allowed?

Tags: discussion

The problem with linking an answer to a blogspot or other blogging websites is that, in most companies, blogspots and others may be disabled(since they're personal websites) - that hampers from getting the answers.

So my question is, should external blogspot links be allowed?

Comment: Related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156003/copying-webpage-content-is-fine-but-linking-to-the-web-page-is-considered-wrong?lq=1

Comment: In *most* companies? Is it still that bad in some places? (Have not seen anything blocked since 1999.)

Comment: @Arjan Our college has a firewall that appears to work on an `allow` list rather than a `block` list, the result being that just about everything is blocked other than the most obvious stuff such as Wikipedia. If a Google search result opens (which itself depends on whether the search gets permitted or not), then you should consider yourself extremely lucky ..

Answer (score 9):

Yes, links to those resources should be allowed.  Links to outside resources should only serve as a *reference*.  If you leave *just* a link as an answer, forcing people to go to a blog or other web site, that's not considered a good answer anyway.  The information from the blog that answers the question should be quoted or paraphrased.  If someone leaves a link-only answer, flag it for removal.

Comment: ah cool.. thanks for the info