# Question about Tutorials/Books/Videos/Examples

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

If any one is new to some technology then he/she wants some tutorials, books, videos, examples for reference, so he/she can start easily.

I asked question on Stack Overflow regarding tutorials, books, videos, examples for Ajax-ce SDK for Panasonic smart tv application development for start up but getting down votes so deleted.

I asked question on programmers about learning iphone for that references which is good to start but getting down votes so deleted.

My question is in which Stack Overflow site should I asked question about tutorials or books or videos or examples for reference to learn any technology?

Comment: You cannot ask such questions on *any* Stack Exchange site; they are shopping recommendations, which the community has determined (long ago and over and over again) are not suitable for the Q&A format.

Comment: See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153220/why-is-asking-for-references-sources-to-study-specific-topics-considered-not-con

Comment: Shopping questions (so named) are more suitable for the various and abundant programming forums out there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it thanks....

Comment: @AshRj got it thanks & for the link of your question...

Comment: @J.Steen got it thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, probably nowhere.

StackExchange sites work by being about Questions that posters have that they are looking for *THE* answer. There is no correct answer to a question requesting some tutorials.

Also, if there was a correct tutorial site / book then who's to say that it'll still be correct in 6 months time? It may have been surpassed by something else, or rewritten.

This is what we term a [shopping request](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), the type of question that doesn't really work on a Q&A site.

You could try asking in the various chat rooms of the sites to see if anyone has any recommendations, but that's probably the only suitable place to ask such questions I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks got it & +1 for shopping request......

Comment: However sometime its  really hard to know/get good source

Comment: @NullPointer Totally agree. It'd be great if there was a big encyclopaedia type thing listing out what books / apps / software etc is good for different purposes, with reviews / ratings etc. Feel free to start that up! I'll think of a name for it.

Comment: Sounds really good and helpful idea